# TextBox inputing data issue with MVVM Light.?

Tags: wpf, textbox, mvvm-light

I am working on WPF MvvmLight application and once I click on first page it navigates to second page. The second page has a textbox on which the focus is set. On this textbox, I am not able to put any data or any character. But I can do copy and paste. What might be the reason for this strange behavior.

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="txtsearchYouTube" Height="25"
    Margin="100,0,100,0" Canvas.Top="275" Width="500"
    Loaded="txtsearchYouTube_Loaded" Canvas.Left="50"
    Text="{Binding SeachKeyWord,Mode=TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: can you sgow how you bind the textbox ?

Comment: Ya sure my                 <TextBox 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    x:Name="txtsearchYouTube"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="100,0,100,0"
                    Canvas.Top="275"
                    Width="500"
                    Loaded="txtsearchYouTube_Loaded"
                    Canvas.Left="50"
                    Text="{Binding SeachKeyWord,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: Hi Felice I had added this binding sample and let me correct I think binding it shouldn't be problem.

Comment: @JitendraJadav, I have made some edits to your question which are pending approval. Once its approved please check to see if nothing important is deleted

Comment: whats the code of your Viewmodel(SearchKeyWord Proeprty) and your txtsearchYouTube_Loaded event. btw when you copy data to your textbox, can you edit your copied stuff?

Comment: sure txtsearchYouTube_Load just set the Focus() and SearchKeyWord  is the property wich set to UpdateTrigger='PropertyChanged'.copy means manually I copied and paste.thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The Binding is not the issue, in fact even if it is wrong, you will still be able to write in that TextBox, it just won't be put in SearchKeyWord. By the way, you mispelled it (you forgot an R in seaRch).

2) If you're really only setting the focus on the loaded event, and **nothing** else, then it's not the problem either.

3) MVVM Light is just a conveniency framework, it does not alter WPF for you as it just provides tools, it definitely doesn't mess with TextBoxes.

That said, here is what I would check in your situation:

- If SearchKeyWord is a **dependency property** look where it is declared to see if there is a callback/coercevalue/validatevalue declared. Since the binding is two-way, it could very well always invalidate the values recieved (preventing you from actually writing anything in there)
- Check all the way up your visual tree, for any **implicit styles** for the TextBox type. They could have triggers that mess up with your data.

Hope this helps,

Bab.

Comment: Thank you : @Baboon I understand my problem is I have register my KeyboadrEvent and whenever I put the value into textbox that time it will goes to all the cases like enter keydown and all but it would be not found any keyword so defaul value set to args.Handle =true so it is alway handle true that is problem..!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whats wrong with your code. but you can help your self. so just remove your binding and loaded event and check if you can put any data in your textbox.
if yes pls post all code from your event and viewmodel otherwise its hard to help.

you wrote you can copy and paste? what does it mean? your textbox show the text you paste in? or your viewmodel got the pasted value?

EDIT: you can also use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check your textbox binding and properties at runtime.